# get object of class that contains value of foreign key and determine if foreign key equal null do action else do another action asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

[![enter image description here][1]][1]`Fax` class:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```

`Department` class:

```
public partial class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public List<Faxis> Faxes { get; set; } 
}
```

`Register` class:

```
public partial class Register
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "كلمة المرور غير مطابقة")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public int? DepartId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartId")]
    public virtual Department Depart { get; set; }
}
```

Fax Razor page

```
public ICollection<Faxis> Faxis { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync(int s = 5, int p=1)
{
    Faxis = _context.Registers
                    .Include(a => a.Depart)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Faxes)
                    .Skip((p - 1) * s).Take(s)
                    .SingleOrDefault(r => r.UserName == HttpContext.Session.GetString("username"))?.Depart.Faxes;

    PageSize = s;
    TotalFaxis = _context.Faxes.Count();
    PageNo = p;
}
```

When each user login they get faxes of their department .. problem here I want users with null value of departId to get all faxes after login .. and I want nav bar to be hidden before login in the layout page

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(int s = 5, int p=1)
{
     var register = _context.Registers.Where(x => x.DepartId.HasValue);

     if (register == null)
     {
         Faxis = _context.Registers
                         .Include(a => a.Depart)
                         .ThenInclude(a => a.Faxes)
                         .Skip((p - 1) * s).Take(s)
                         .SingleOrDefault(r => r.UserName == HttpContext.Session.GetString("username"))?
                       .Depart.Faxes;
    }
    else
    {
        Faxis = await _context.Faxes.Skip((p - 1) * s).Take(s)
                                .Include(f => f.FaxRespond)
                                .Include(f => f.Department)
                                .ToListAsync();
    }

    PageSize = s;
    TotalFaxis = _context.Faxes.Count();
    PageNo = p;
}
```

I try this but it doesn't solve my problem

finally solved as picture
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoVKD.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,we usually access the Auth state of User with `HttpContext.User`,Check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) related with Authentication in Asp.net core

Secondly, If you expect the `Department` attribute of `Register` entity could be null

you should set it as below:

```
public virtual Department? Depart { get; set; }
```

If you want to show all fax when the user's departId is null,try as below

```
var currentregister = _context.Register.Include(x => x.Depart).ThenInclude(y => y.Faxes).FirstOrDefault(r => r.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
           
           

if (currentregister != null)
{
  this.Faxis = currentregister.DepartId == null ? _context.Fax.ToList() : currentregister.Depart.Faxes;
}
```

If you want nav bar to be hidden before login

check the current user :

```
this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name!=null
```

if you add the Navbar as a layoutpage

try in @ section:

```
@{
 if(...){
 Layout=null
}
}
```

I tried with a minimal example as below:

```
public void OnGet(string? username)
        {
            if (username != null)
            {


                var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
             new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
            };
                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
                var claimsprincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

                HttpContext.User = claimsprincipal;
            }


            var currentregister = _context.Register.Include(x => x.Depart).ThenInclude(y => y.Faxes).FirstOrDefault(r => r.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
           
           

            if (currentregister != null)
            {
                this.Faxis = currentregister.DepartId == null ? _context.Fax.ToList() : currentregister.Depart.Faxes;
            }

        }
```

Page:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Id
        </th>
        <th>
            DepartId
        </th>
        <th>
            Fax
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach(var item in Model.Faxis)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Id
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.DepartmentId
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.FaxString
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

   
</table>

@if (this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name!=null)
    {
        <a>NavBar</a>
    }
```

DB:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your efforts @Ruikai .. code return Null Exception in the Fax Page .. can you help me

Comment: username value is null !

Comment: Have you tried with  string? username ,I'm going to rest,if you still have problem,i'll reply you tomorrow

Comment: The same result .. awaiting your reply ,thank you again